# How to copy the contents of a text file to the clipboard?

Tags: vbscript

I use the following code VBS to read a text file. How can I save the contents of this text file to my computer clipboard to paste elsewhere?

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFileToRead, strFileText, content

Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\1.txt",1)
strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
objFileToRead.Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do it using `clip` command line :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title : Title = "Copy the contents of a text file to the clipboard"
Dim File2Read : File2Read = "C:\1.txt"
If CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FileExists(File2Read) Then 
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd.exe /c clip < "& File2Read &"",0,TRUE
    MsgBox "The contents of file : " & chr(34) & File2Read & chr(34) & vbCrlf & _
    " is copied to the clipboard !",vbInformation,Title
Else
    MsgBox "Check if the " & chr(34) & File2Read & chr(34) &" exists !",vbExclamation,Title
End If
```

---

***EDIT :*** Save a ping test into file and copy it to clipboard !

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title : Title = "Copy the contents of a text file to the clipboard"
Dim File2Read : File2Read = "E:\Yahoo_Ping.txt"
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "CMD /C Ping www.yahoo.com > "& File2Read &"",1,True
If CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FileExists(File2Read) Then 
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "CMD /U /C clip < "& File2Read &"",0,TRUE
    MsgBox "The contents of file : " & chr(34) & File2Read & chr(34) & vbCrlf & _
    " is copied to the clipboard !",vbInformation,Title
Else
    MsgBox "Check if the " & chr(34) & File2Read & chr(34) &" exists !",vbExclamation,Title
End If
```

---

With Batch and Powershell :

```
@echo off
Title Set-Clipboard and Get-ClipBoard with Powershell and Batch
Set "InputFile=%Temp%\%~n0.txt"
echo Please be patient ....
Ping www.stackoverflow.com > "%InputFile%"
Set "OutPutFile=%userprofile%\Desktop\MyClipBoard.txt"
Call :RunPS-Get-ClipBoard "%InputFile%" "%OutPutFile%"
Cls & Type "%OutPutFile%"
Pause & Exit
REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------
:RunPS-Get-ClipBoard <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
Set psCmd="&{Set-Clipboard -Value (GC '"%~1"') | Get-ClipBoard}"
If Exist "%~2" Del "%~2"
@for /F "tokens=*delims=" %%i in ('Powershell %psCmd%') do >> "%~2" echo %%i
Goto:eof
REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: In the text file with UTF8, the "∩╗┐" are copied at the beginning of the text!!

Comment: @2019meganz How did you obtain the file `c:\1.txt` from what ? exactly ?

Comment: I tested in another path. @Hackoo

Comment: I tested in C: and another path. The problem remains. @Hackoo

Comment: @2019meganz Test my last edit code and tell me how its works on your side ?

Comment: ) I tested your edited code and there was no problem. The only problem is with the UTF-8 text files. This is not a problem if the text file is ANSI encoding. But ANSI does not accept many characters. For example, Asian letters are not stored in it. I entered the UTF-8 to NSAI conversion code before executing your code. Extra characters (∩╗┐) were deleted, but if the file has Asian characters, convert it to "??? ?? ???". Thank you again for following up. @Hackoo

Comment: Can it be recognized that the file is in UTF-8 format and copy to clipboard from the first three characters onwards?